# How to setup settings and export .mov file from shotgrid RV player using subprocess?

Tags: python

I am working on shotgrid RV player, where I am trying to import two different `.mov` files and overlapp them and then export the resultant `.mov` file.

I am providing more context here below:

Script which I am using is as follows :

```
import subprocess

def open_shotgun_rv_player(file_path_1, file_path_2, export_path):
    rv_executable = 'C:/Program Files/ShotGrid/RV-2022.3.1/bin/rv.exe'  # Replace with the actual path to the 'rv' executable
    # command = [rv_executable,'-help']
    command = [rv_executable, file_path_1,file_path_2,'view %s'%('add')] #  # Add the export option to the command
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    stdout_lines = stdout.decode().splitlines()
    stderr_lines = stderr.decode().splitlines()

    print("Standard error:")
    for line in stderr_lines:
        print(line)

file_path_1 = 'C:/...../dummy_0200_layout_v01.mov'
file_path_2 = 'C:/..../dummy_0300_animatic_v05.mov'
export_path = 'Q:/..../export.mov'
open_shotgun_rv_player(file_path_1, file_path_2, export_path)
```

I am getting this following error :

```
ERROR: Open of 'view add' failed: unsupported media type.
```

I have tried `comp add` rather than `view` as well but i got similar error in that case as well.

Now to get idea from the software perspective I am trying to do the following operations.

[image]

[image]

I haven't added the export path yet as I tried few things but I was getting errors well. So any help on these issues would be really helpful.

Thanks & Regrads